# Zend\Http\Client call on localhost (server-side)

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm working on a medium Zend Framework 2 project (LAMP) and I need to perform an ajax call locally (ex: http://localhost/api/myapi).

This is the code of the function:

```
        private function getSettings() {
            $client = new HttpClient();

            $client->setAdapter('Zend\Http\Client\Adapter\Curl');
            $client->setMethod('GET');

            $client->setUri('http://localhost/api/settings/0');

            $config = array(
                    'curloptions' => array(CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false),
                    'timeout' => 3000000
            );

            $client->setOptions($config);

            $requestHeaders = $client->getRequest()->getHeaders();
            $requestHeaders->addHeaderLine('Accept: application/json');

            $resp = $client->send();

            return $resp->getContent();
    }
```

My problem is that when I exec this function I receive this error:

> The requested URL /api/settings/0 was not found on this server

What am I doing wrong? How can I perform a "local" request with ZF2's Http Client class?

Comment: Check `http://localhost/api/settings/0` actually exists?